# Merge pandas DataFrames based on time interval

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am attempting to merge two DataFrames df_1 containing a weekly count and df_2 containing the average count per month.

Weekly count (df_1) seen below.

```html
date               Direct_Connection     Indirect_Connection
2014-12-07         36                   124
2014-12-14         38                   111
2014-12-21         28                   95
2014-12-28         15                   58
2015-01-04         5                   9
2015-01-11         22                   85
2015-01-18         49                   174
2015-01-25         47                   171
2015-02-01         54                   187
2015-02-08          45                        216
2015-02-15          29                        125
2015-02-22         22                   63
2015-03-01         27                   96
```

Monthly Average (df_2) seen below.

```html
date       Direct_Connection   Indirect_Connection
2014-12-31 29.25               97.0
2015-01-31 30.75               109.75
2015-02-28 37.5               147.75
2015-03-31 31.0               119.0
```

The merge I would like to complete would add an 'Associated Monthly Average' columns to df_1 (Weekly Count) for both 'Direct_connection' and 'Indirect Connection'

An example of my desired output can be seen below.

```html
date               Direct_Connection Assoc_dir_avg  Indirect_Connection Ass_indir_avg
2014-12-07         36               29.5           124                 97
2014-12-14         38               29.5           111                 97
2014-12-21         28               29.5           95                  97
2014-12-28         15               29.5           58                  97
2015-01-04         5               30.5           9                   109.75 
2015-01-11         22               30.5           85                  109.75
2015-01-18         49               30.5           174                 109.75
2015-01-25         47               30.5           171                 109.75
2015-02-01         54               37.5           187                 147.75
2015-02-08          45                    37.5           216             147.75
2015-02-15          29                    37.5           125             147.75
2015-02-22         22               37.5            63                 147.75
2015-03-01         27               31              96                 119
```

The above DataFrames are only a brief snippet of the entire DF's, which span over a number of years.

Any assistance anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
# Cast to date if not done already 
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'].str.strip(), format='%Y-%m-%d')
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'].str.strip(), format='%Y-%m-%d')

from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

df=df1.merge(df2, left_on=(df1['date'] + MonthEnd(1)), right_on='date').rename(columns={'Direct_Connection_x':'Direct_Connection',
                                                                        'Indirect_Connection_x':'Indirect_Connection',
                                                                        'Direct_Connection_y':'Assoc_dir_avg',
                                                                        'Indirect_Connection_y':'Ass_indir_avg',
                                                                        'date_x':'date'}).drop('date_y', axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
         date                      Direct_Connection  Indirect_Connection  \
0  2014-12-07                                     36                124.0   
1  2014-12-14                                     38                111.0   
2  2014-12-21                                     28                 95.0   
3  2014-12-28                                     15                 58.0   
4  2015-01-04                                      5                  9.0   
5  2015-01-11                                     22                 85.0   
6  2015-01-18                                     49                174.0   
7  2015-01-25                                     47                171.0   
8  2015-02-01                                     54                187.0   
9  2015-02-08          45                        216                  NaN   
10 2015-02-15                29                                     125.0   
11 2015-02-22                                     22                 63.0   
12 2015-03-01                                     27                 96.0   

    Assoc_dir_avg  Ass_indir_avg  
0           29.25          97.00  
1           29.25          97.00  
2           29.25          97.00  
3           29.25          97.00  
4           30.75         109.75  
5           30.75         109.75  
6           30.75         109.75  
7           30.75         109.75  
8           37.50         147.75  
9           37.50         147.75  
10          37.50         147.75  
11          37.50         147.75  
12          31.00         119.00
```

Comment: @Lane.D you are welcome! If this worked, you can upvote/mark as answer so people searching for something similar find it helpful!